# Change default sounds of gnome-clocks app

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, clock

I'm use [gnome-clocks](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Clocks) for its timer option. This app is very simple and effective. But I can't change the default sounds of the alarm and the timer. I tried setting the configurations in **dconf** and `Settings > Sound > Sound Effects` but it's impossible to change.

Where is the config file for this app? How can I change the default sounds?

Answer (score 7):

A better solution to this problem sounds more complex that it actually is.

## 1. Create a custom sound profile

Copy an existing profile:

```
cp -rv /usr/share/sounds/freedesktop ~/.local/share/sounds/my-custom-profile
```

Open the `index.theme` file and change the name to *my-custom-profile*. Replace the sounds you want to change with your own, but be careful, a long sound for *audio-volume-change* for example will play on volume change until it is completed. For the clocks app you want to look for these files:

- complete.oga
- alarm-clock-elapsed.oga

I have seen ogg and oga files being used, I tried FLAC but that did not work (in the flac container). You may need to convert your sounds to Vorbis.

## 2. Change your current sound profile

Open dconf-editor, go to `/org/gnome/desktop/sound` and change `theme-name` value to your custom profile e.g. *my-custom-profile*.

I'm not exactly sure how the sound profile is matched, either by folder name or by the name field in the theme file, it seems to be the folder name. I suggest to have an identical name in both places.

## Resources

- [Sound themes in Linux: What every user should know](https://opensource.com/article/18/6/sound-themes-linux)
- [Freedesktop.org: Sound Theme and Naming Specifications](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/sound-theme-spec/)
- [How do I switch to another sound theme?](https://askubuntu.com/q/65545/40581) — N.B.: gconftool-2 has been replaced with gsettings if I didn't get it backwards.
- [How do I install a "sound theme?"](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1605567)

Comment: LiveWireBT this solutions is more complex but more smart. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

From the source-code: gnome-clock seems to use two sound-files:

- complete.oga
- alarm-clock-elapsed.oga

On my system these files are in the folder `/usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo`.

So you could make a backup-copy of the original two sound-files, and replace them by some other sound-files (preferably from the same folder).

Comment: This may not work if a different sound theme is configured which provides the respective sounds. I do not recommended to modify or replace files in /usr as this will change them for every user.